# How to create a image header page using php & html

Tags: php, html, image, ssl, header

I want to create a Image Header Page on php, where i can include some urls with non-ssl to have a fully ssl encrypted webpage, like this service from duckduckgo:

```
http://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-JOqxgp-ZWe0/U3BtyEQlEiI/AAAAAAAAOfg/Doq6Q2MwIKA/s1600/google-logo-874x288.png
```

At this time my page shows me the image like duckduckgo, but if i include a url like the schema from duckduck go (www.example.org/img.php?img=http://www.image.php/img.jpg). the images does not load. I think its a problem with image header.

My code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $img = $_GET["img"];
    echo imagejpeg($img);
?>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width; height=device-height;" name="viewport">
</head>
<body>
<img class="decoded" alt='<?php echo $img; ?>' src='<?php echo $img; ?>'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is loading a image from a server via your server to the client.
You can do this by making a public separated php file, for example image.php.

So make a php file image.php with the code you've on top of the html page. You only must have this piece of code on top:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Now you can call it like: http://your-domain.com/image.php?img=https://your-domain.com/images/your-image.jpg

Comment: It returns me a error like this: "the image (url) can not be displayed because it contains errors."

Comment: You've to use the imagecreatefromjpeg function for this. The imagejpg function doesn't load a url or file but expexts a jpg as parameter. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to create the image, and after the image was created, you call imagejpeg() function.

```
$img = $_GET['img'];
$generated_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);
imagejpeg($generated_img);
```

You can process the image outside your code, and refer to this code in src attribute of image element

```
<img src="img.php" />
```

Answer (score 0):

arjan speaks correctly.
but if you wish to have the php in the same file make sure to exit. and also make sure there is NOTHING echoed before the header function call...this includes spaces and new lines prior to the opening php tag.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if ($_GET["img"] != '')
    {
        $img = $_GET["img"];
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        echo imagejpeg($img);
        exit();
    }
?>
```